# Iterating through dom elements in a class relatively

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a quiz using jquery and would like to be able to change the color of all the button elements in a question class relatively. Many examples I've seen show how to do it in an absolute manner--meaning all the elements of *all* instances of a class change color. How do you iterate through a single *instance* of div class?

```js
function clickFn() {
  console.log('in click event')
  $( "button" ).each(function() {
    if ($(this)
        $(this).toggleClass( "buttonSelected" );
  });
};
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: grey;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 20vw;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.buttonSelected {
  background-color: #f00;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 20vw;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='question'>
  <span class='question_body' onclick="clickFn()">Question n </span></p>
<button class="button" onclick="clickFn()">Wrong Answer</button></p>
<button class="button" onclick="clickFn()">Correct Answer</button></p>
<button class="button" onclick="clickFn()">Wrong Answer</button></p>
<button class="button" onclick="clickFn()">Wrong Answer</button></p>
</div>
<div id='question'>
  <span class='question_body'>Question n </span></p>
<button class="button">Wrong Answer</button></p>
<button class="button">Correct Answer</button></p>
<button class="button">Wrong Answer</button></p>
<button class="button">Wrong Answer</button></p>
</div>
```

This will change the color

Comment: Is your goal to only select all the buttons inside each div separately, so you are not applying style to all of them  ?

Comment: Yes, I want all buttons in a div instance to be grayed out when you select an answer, but not all buttons globally.

Comment: Checkout my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have a syntax error in `if($(this)` (missing brace)
2. Don't use the same `id` attributes for multiple elements. It's an *identifier* and as such should be unique.
3. No need for loops. Simply use [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) or [`.closest('div')`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
4. (Side note)
   [It's not a good practice to use javascript attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)

---

Is this what you want?

```js
$(".button").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().find('.button').toggleClass("buttonSelected")
   .end().find('.good').toggleClass("buttonGood");
});

// Or .closest():
// $(".button").click(function() {
//    $(this).closest('div').find('.button').toggleClass("buttonSelected")
//    .end().find('.good').toggleClass("buttonGood");
// });
```

```css
.button {
    background-color: grey;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width: 20vw;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.buttonSelected {
    background-color: #f00;
}
.buttonGood {
    background-color: #66ff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id='question1'>
     <span class='question_body'>Question n </span></p>
     <button class="button">Wrong Answer</button></p>
     <button class="button good">Correct Answer</button></p>
     <button class="button">Wrong Answer</button></p>
     <button class="button">Wrong Answer</button></p>
    </div>
    <div id='question2'>
     <span class='question_body'>Question n </span></p>
     <button class="button">Wrong Answer</button></p>
     <button class="button good">Correct Answer</button></p>
     <button class="button">Wrong Answer</button></p>
     <button class="button">Wrong Answer</button></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container">
<div class="questions">
  <button>Correct Answer</button>
  <button>Wrong Answer</button>
  <button>Correct Answer</button>
  <button>Wrong Answer</button>
</div>

<div class="questions">
  <button>Correct Answer</button>
  <button>Wrong Answer</button>
  <button>Correct Answer</button>
  <button>Wrong Answer</button>
</div>
</div>




<script type="text/javascript">
$('#container button').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click', function(){
        var allButtons = $(this).parent().find('button'); 
        console.log(allButtons);
         $(allButtons).each(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass( "buttonSelected" );
      });
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the `id` attribute should be unique in the same document so better to replace the ids `question` by a class :

```
<div class='question'>
```

Then it will be better if you avoid the inline-events lile `onClick()` and remove the extra `</p>` in the end of every button, so your code will be correct and more readable :

```
<div class='question'>
    <span class='question_body'>Question n </span>
    <button class="button">Wrong Answer</button>
    <button class="button">Correct Answer</button>
    <button class="button">Wrong Answer</button>
    <button class="button">Wrong Answer</button>
</div>
<div class='question'>
    <span class='question_body'>Question n </span>
    <button class="button">Wrong Answer</button>
    <button class="button">Correct Answer</button>
    <button class="button">Wrong Answer</button>
    <button class="button">Wrong Answer</button>
</div>
```

Instead create a click event in your javascript code and use **[`siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** method in place of `parent()` and `each()` to change the class of button in same level of clicked one :

```
$('body').on('click', 'button', function(){
    if( $(this).hasClass('clicked') ){
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).siblings('button').removeClass('buttonSelected clicked');
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass('buttonSelected').addClass('clicked');
        $(this).siblings('button').removeClass('clicked').addClass('buttonSelected');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Working Snippet

```js
$('body').on('click', 'button', function(){
  if( $(this).hasClass('clicked') )
  {
    $(this).removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).siblings('button').removeClass('buttonSelected clicked');
  }else{
    $(this).removeClass('buttonSelected').addClass('clicked');
    $(this).siblings('button').removeClass('clicked').addClass('buttonSelected');
  }
});
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: grey;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 20vw;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.buttonSelected {
  background-color: #f00;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 20vw;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='question'>
  <span class='question_body'>Question n </span>
  <button class="button">Wrong Answer</button>
  <button class="button">Correct Answer</button>
  <button class="button">Wrong Answer</button>
  <button class="button">Wrong Answer</button>
</div>
<div id='question'>
  <span class='question_body'>Question n </span>
  <button class="button">Wrong Answer</button>
  <button class="button">Correct Answer</button>
  <button class="button">Wrong Answer</button>
  <button class="button">Wrong Answer</button>
</div>
```